# Test only evaluating first element of array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match

I loop through the values of a form, to check that each field has 4 digits. My problem is currently it validates true or false only on the match for the first field `$card1`...

```
function cardcheck ($card1,$card2,$card3,$card4)
{
    $cards = array($card1,$card2,$card3,$card4);
    $regex = "/[0-9]{4}/";
    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    if (! preg_match ($regex,$cards[$i]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a return statement inside your for loop. It'll return on the first iteration, whether it's true or false. You need to move that outside the `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning (by using `return ...`) something in the first iteration every time (boolean condition with an else).

You need to put the `return true` outside the loop statement:

```
function cardcheck ($card1,$card2,$card3,$card4)
{
    $cards = array($card1,$card2,$card3,$card4);
    $regex = "/[0-9]{4}/";
    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
        if (! preg_match ($regex,$cards[$i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function cardcheck ($card1,$card2,$card3,$card4)
{
    $cards = array($card1,$card2,$card3,$card4);
    $regex = "/[0-9]{4}/";

    for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
       if (! preg_match ($regex,$cards[$i]))
       {
           return false;
       }

    return true;
}
```